# R: Generic plot function takes two parameters, but what if I only want it ot take 1?

Tags: r

```
> plot
function (x, y, ...) 
UseMethod("plot")
<bytecode: 0x000000000826f240>
<environment: namespace:graphics>
```

If you type in `plot`, you get the above. Note that the function takes two parameters.

Now I have a class, `A`, and I'd like to give it its own `plot`-method. So I can write

`plot.A <- function(object)`

but note that I only want a `plot`-function that takes 1 argument (and not `x, y`).

So what do I do?

Comment: `plot.A <- function(x, ...) {}`. Just like `graphics:::plot.data.frame`

Comment: But I was told that methods must take the same parameters as the generic function? So since generic.plot takes x, y, our method plot.a must also take x, y?

Comment: I think `plot.data.frame` is a pretty good counter-example. The `...` gives some flexibility, I guess.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do that you cannot get to work? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this? Basically you need to just make the `plot.A()` function to be whatever you need it to be. I find the following resource helpful.

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html

```
A <- function(x) {
  if (!is.data.frame(x)) stop("X must be a data.frame")
  structure(list(x), class = "A")
}

plot.A <- function(x, ...) {
  plot(x[[1]]$mpg, x[[1]]$cyl, ...)
}

a <- A(mtcars)

plot(a)
```